# Intro to AI Problem: Calculate color of pixel given coordinates

Tags: camera, artificial-intelligence, coordinates

Assuming a three-dimensional scene as shown in the diagram below (note: this is only an illustrative diagram). The camera coordinates are (0,0,-1), and the center of the screen plane is at the origin and perpendicular to the z-axis. There is a sphere in the space with the center coordinates (0, 0, 4) and a radius of √2. The color value of the sphere itself is 0.2. The position of the light source is (0, 5, -1) with a color of 0.8. The rest of the space is completely black with a color of 0.

(1) Calculate the color of the pixels on the screen corresponding to the three-dimensional coordinates (0, 1, 0), (0, 0.25, 0), and (0, -0.25, 0) under perspective projection.

(2) Calculate the color of the pixels corresponding to the above three coordinates under orthographic projection.

Hint: There is no reflection when the angle between the light ray and the normal of the reflecting surface exceeds 90°.

Here is the original question in Chinese as I go to a Chinese uni. Thank you.
假设有三维场景如下图所示(注意，仅为示意图)。相机坐标为 (0,0,−1)，屏幕 平面中心位于原点，且与  轴垂直。空间中有一球体，球心坐标为 (0, 0, 4) ，半径为√2。球
体本身的颜色数值为 0.2 。光源位置为 (0, 5, −1) ，颜色为0.8。其他空间为全黑，颜色为0 。 (1)计算透视投影下屏幕上三维坐标为(0, 1, 0) 、(0, 0.25, 0)、 (0, −0.25, 0) 的像素的颜色。 (2)计算在正交投影下，上述三个个像素的颜色。 提示:光线在反射面背侧，即光线法线夹角超过 90°时，没有反射。

for part 1 I got that for (0,1,0) it's 1 and then for the other two they're both just 0.2. I don't understand part 2.